# How to count number of columns Excel file in ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, closedxml

I tried to do that using code:

```
worksheet.Columns.count();
```

But there is not method `count()` for `Columns`

All code is:

```
 class ExcelReader
    {

        private XLWorkbook workbook;
        private string file;
        private IXLWorksheet worksheet;


        public ExcelReader(string file) {

            this.workbook = new XLWorkbook(file);
        }

        private void ChooseWorksheet(int sheet) {

            this.worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(sheet);
        } 

        public int NumberColumns() {

            return this.worksheet.Columns.Count();
        }
}
```

Comment: Tough it may seem obvious to you, what **exactly** is worksheet? Please provide a little bit more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code from https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML
Count should work using LINQ, since `IXLColumns` implemments `IEnumerable<IXLColumn>`
    IXLColumns: IEnumerable

If you are getting a method missing on Count, means you are missing

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing. The following worked for me:

`worksheet.Columns().Count()`